# Module federation with react router v6

Tags: reactjs, react-router, vite, webpack-module-federation

I have a bi-directional module federation which is like this:

I have created two separate projects, one for "main" and one for "subscription".

MAIN is like this:

```
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import { Suspense, lazy } from "react";

// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-return
const Slave = lazy(async () => await import("slave/Slave"));

const App = () => {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route
          path="slave"
          element={
            <Suspense fallback="Loading...">
              <Slave />
            </Suspense>
          }
        />
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
};

export default App;
```

And in vite.config.ts, I have:

```
import federation from "@originjs/vite-plugin-federation";
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react";
import { defineConfig } from "vite";

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    react(),
    federation({
      name: "master",
      filename: "remoteEntry.js",
      // Modules to expose
      exposes: {
        "./Master": "./src/App",
      },

      remotes: [
          {
            slave: "http://localhost:4000/assets/remoteEntry.js",
          },
        ],
      shared: ["react", "react-dom"],
    }),
  ],
  build: {
    modulePreload: false,
    target: "esnext",
    minify: false,
    cssCodeSplit: false,
  },
});
```

And for my Slave app I have the following:

```
import "./App.css";
import { Suspense, lazy } from "react";

// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-return
const Master = lazy(async () => await import("master/Master"));
const App = () => {
  return (
    <Suspense fallback="Loading...">
      <Master />
    </Suspense>
  );
};

export default App;
```

And a Router.tsx

```
import { Route } from "react-router-dom";

const Router = () => {
  return <Route path="/slave" element={<div>SLAVE</div>} />;
};

export default Router;
```

and my vite.config.ts

```
import federation from "@originjs/vite-plugin-federation";
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react";

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default {
  plugins: [
    react(),
    federation({
      name: "slave",
      filename: "remoteEntry.js",
      // Modules to expose
      exposes: {
        "./Slave": "./src/Router",
      },

      remotes: [
        {
          master: "http://localhost:4001/assets/remoteEntry.js",
        },
      ],

      shared: ["react", "react-dom"],
    }),
  ],
  build: {
    modulePreload: false,
    target: "esnext",
    minify: false,
    cssCodeSplit: false,
  },
};
```

I want to achieve the same flow as they have here: https://engineering.telia.no/blog/micro-frontends-with-webpack-module-federation

where I can still show master layout for each slave.

But I get an error saying something is wrong with Route.

I expect  to behave the same way as